# Different size objects in GridView builder

Tags: flutter, dart, frontend

I am currently working with Flutter and I am having trouble trying to achieve a grid that can render squares and rectangles. Here is my current code:

`GridView.builder` code:

```
child: GridView.builder(
                      gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                        crossAxisCount: 6,
                      ),
                      itemCount: widget.squareColors.length,
                      itemBuilder: ((BuildContext context, int index) {
                        return GestureDetector(
                          onTap: signOut,
                          child: index != 4
                              ? GridSquare(
                                  color: widget.squareColors[index],
                                  rect: false)
                              : GridSquare(
                                  color: widget.squareColors[index],
                                  rect: true),
                        );
                      }))),
```

`GridSquare` code:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      width: rect ? 112 : 56, //THIS DID NOT WORK
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
          border: Border.all(
            color: Colors.grey.shade100,
            width: 0.25,
          ),
          color: color,
          boxShadow: [
            BoxShadow(
              color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.05),
              offset: const Offset(0, 2),
              blurRadius: 2,
              spreadRadius: 1,
            ),
            BoxShadow(
              color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.05),
              offset: const Offset(0, -2),
              blurRadius: 2,
              spreadRadius: 1,
            ),
            BoxShadow(
              color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.05),
              offset: const Offset(2, 0),
              blurRadius: 2,
              spreadRadius: 1,
            ),
            BoxShadow(
              color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.05),
              offset: const Offset(-2, 0),
              blurRadius: 2,
              spreadRadius: 1,
            ),
          ]),
    );
```

So I set a width for my squares but this did not accomplish anything. I am also not sure if I should be using a `GridView.builder` to achieve what I want to achieve so any suggestions that do not involve `GridView.builder`

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zQNC3.png)

Above is a screenshot of what I want to achieve (Except the differents squares and rectangles should be touching each other separated by a single pixel thick border). Also, sorry for not being able to embed images, I do not have enough rep yet.

Answer (score 0):

From the code that you have given i have created a simple example. for the width factor i have not used grid view but i have used the wrap widget. I have added the sample example below

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MaterialApp(home: MyApp()));
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Signup App'),
      ),
      body: MyHomePage(
        squareColors: squareColors,
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  final List<Color> squareColors;
  const MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.squareColors}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Wrap(
      direction: Axis.horizontal,
      children: widget.squareColors
          .map(
            (i) => i == Colors.red
                ? GridSquare(color: i, rect: false)
                : GridSquare(color: i, rect: true),
          )
          .toList(),
    );
  }
}

final squareColors = [
  Colors.red,
  Colors.blue,
  Colors.green,
  Colors.amberAccent,
  Colors.black12,
  Colors.blueAccent,
  Colors.brown
];

class GridSquare extends StatelessWidget {
  final bool rect;
  final Color color;
  const GridSquare({
    Key? key,
    required this.rect,
    required this.color,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      width: rect ? 150 : 56,
      height: 100, //THIS DID NOT WORK
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
          border: Border.all(
            color: Colors.grey.shade100,
            width: 0.25,
          ),
          color: color,
          boxShadow: [
            BoxShadow(
              color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.05),
              offset: const Offset(0, 2),
              blurRadius: 2,
              spreadRadius: 1,
            ),
            BoxShadow(
              color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.05),
              offset: const Offset(0, -2),
              blurRadius: 2,
              spreadRadius: 1,
            ),
            BoxShadow(
              color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.05),
              offset: const Offset(2, 0),
              blurRadius: 2,
              spreadRadius: 1,
            ),
            BoxShadow(
              color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.05),
              offset: const Offset(-2, 0),
              blurRadius: 2,
              spreadRadius: 1,
            ),
          ]),
    );
  }
}
```

I have also gone through one of the package which is

https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_layout_grid

I have not used it but you can check it out it might also be helpful as this one has dynamic height and width for the grid.